# Using ISNUMERIC fails in condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, type-conversion

I have a table like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE #table (Id INT, Field NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (1, 'SomeText')
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (2, '1234')
```

For some reasons I need to query this table and get the sum of `Field` if it is numeric and return `''` if it is not. I tried it like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1 THEN SUM(CONVERT(MONEY, Field)) ELSE '' END
FROM #table
GROUP BY Field
```

But this query leads to the following exception:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

I even changed the `ELSE` case from `''` to `0` but I still get the same message.

Why do I get the exception? As far as I know, `SUM(...)` should not be executed when `ISNUMERIC(Field)` returns 0.

Comment: this would fail anyway, since a `CASE` expression can return just one datatype. In your case, you are using `SUM` on a `MONEY`  datatype (which returns `MONEY`), or `''` which is obviously a string

Comment: @Lamak that's why I changed `''` to `0` to check if this would help. However, the message still appears.

Comment: because you should use the `CASE` expression inside the `SUM` for starters: `SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1 THEN Field END)`

Comment: That's a point. But why does the error appear when I leave it outside `SUM`?

Comment: Although you have already accepted an answer, i'd caution you against using ISNUMERIC for most cases similar to this. Are the only potential values varchar and int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select sum(case when  ISNUMERIC(Field)=1 then cast(field as money) else 0 end)
 from #table
 Group By Field
```

Returns

```
(No column name)
1234.00
0.00
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now :) the only thing I don't understand is why I only get the exception when I leave the `CASE` statement outside `SUM`.

Comment: @diiN_ Happy to help.  With the case outside of the sum, you will get a data type confict.  Inside, we normalize the data type.

Answer (score 0):

Working with mixed datatypes can be a real pain.  Where possible, consider table designs that avoid this.  To further complicate matters, IsNumeric does not always return [what you might expect](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Filtering out the non-numerics before aggregating is one way to go:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CONVERT(MONEY, Field)) 
FROM 
    #table
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1
GROUP BY 
    Field
;
```

Comment: The problem is that I also need a value (for example `0`) for those fields that aren't numeric.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti provides a better solution than my own.  This will do what you want.